# MySQL IF with CONCAT AND DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, if-statement, concatenation, date-format

I have the following statement, which returns empty values for 'label':

```
SELECT *,
IF (
    `date_to` IS NULL,
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`date_from`, '%D %M %Y'), ' ', `location`),
    CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`date_from`, '%D %M %Y'), ' - ', DATE_FORMAT(`date_to`, '%D %M %Y'), ' ', `location`)
) AS `label`
FROM `courses`
ORDER BY `date_from` ASC
```

The `date_from` and `date_to` columns are both DATE types, and the second one might contain a default value of `0000-00-00`.

Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: What does `empty` mean for you?

Comment: by empty I mean there's no value associated with the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DATE_FORMAT(cast('0000-00-00' as date), '%D %M %Y')` returns NULL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/20003), therefore the entire `CONCAT` will also become null.

Perhaps you should also compare `date_to` to the value '0000-00-00' in the `IF` condition?

Comment: The IF statement actually evaluates ok as I've tested it with hard coded values and it returns the right value based on the 'IS NULL' condition - as in mysql date field with '0000-00-00' is actually equal NULL. As you can see from my example - if it is 'NULL' then `date_to` field is not part of the equation - therefore it wouldn't really return NULL in this case.